# count occurrence of char(array) in sentences(array) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

How can we find and count the occurrences in the following sentences?

```
sentences = [
    'black im yello'
    'green black and white'
    'green green green green green greenana'
    'i have no color'
]

find_char = [
    'green',
    'black',
    'white'
]
```

should return

```
output = {
   'sentence 1' : 1 // just black
   'sentence 2' : 3 // green black white
   'sentence 3' : 6 // 5 green and green in 'green'ana
   'sentence 4' : 0
}
```

Here's my current code

```
var output = {};

for (var i = sentences.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var output_tmp = {}; 
    var occurance = 0; 
    for (x = 0; x < find_char.length; x++) {        
        j = 0;
        output_tmp[find_char[x]] = 0;
        // search if sentences then -1, if > -1 then there is a match
        while ((j = sentences[i].indexOf(find_char[x], j)) > -1) { 
            output_tmp[find_char[x]]++; 
            j++ 
        }
        occurance += output_tmp[find_char[x]];
    }
    output[i] = { 'sentence_no': i,  'occurance' : occurance};
}
```

Is there a better way way doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Combine all words into a single regular expression and apply it to each sentence:

```
sentences = [
    'black im yello',
    'green black and white',
    'green green green green green greenana',
    'i have no color'
]

words = [
    'green',
    'black',
    'white'
]

re = new RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi')

counts = sentences.map(function(sent) {
    return (sent.match(re) || []).length
})
```

This prints in the console:

```
[1, 3, 6, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript's [match method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) to optimize your code. For example, to find the number of "green"s that appear in a sentence, you could use the expression

```
sentences[i].match(/green/g).length)
```

So your code would look like

```
for( s in sentences ){
  var occurences = 0;
  for( f in find_char )
    occurences += (sentences[s].match(new RegExp(find_char[f], "g")) || []).length
  output[s] = { 'sentence_no': s,  'occurance' : occurences};
}
```

Comment: Needs some improvements for zero matches - null has no "length" property

Comment: Uh, and did I forget to fret about the for-in-loop over arrays? :-)